# django restframework _ OneToOne field save()

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two models in my project. Model A and B. Model B has a 'OneToOne' relationship with model A. I wrote a serializer class for model B. in ".create()" function  I have a problem with saving model B, because I need to override the save() function in B model for inserting Slug value. The error is:

> save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'force_insert'

```
class A(models.Model):
    address = models.Charfield(max_length=160)

class b(models.Model):
    a = models.OneToOneField(AdIfo, related_name='ad_info', primary_key=True,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, db_index=True, blank=True)

    def save(self):
        self.slug ="%d%s" %(self.pk, slugify(self.title))
        super(B, self).save()
```

serializers.py

```
class ASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = A
        fields = "__all__"


class BSerilizer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    a = ASerializer(many=False, required=False, allow_null=True)
    slug = serializers.SlugField(read_only=True)

     class Meta:
        model = B
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        info_data = validated_data.pop('ad_info')
        A.objects.create(**info_data)
        ad = B.objects.update_or_create(**validated_data)
        A.objects.update_or_create(ad_info=adgame, **info_data)
        ad.save()
        return ad
```

Comment: You didn't copy/paste + modify your code properly (see syntax highlighting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well your problem is you are trying to make model A and model B then.the model B depends on primary key of model A .this structure you made is making model A and there is no relating on model B and then you are creating model A again.
you just need to create model A and then model B but you should refer the model B id to model A. i know its confusing but try this :

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    info_data = validated_data.pop('ad_info')
    info = A.objects.create(**info_data)
    ad = B.objects.create(pk=info.id, **validated_data)
    return ad
```

> pk=info.id is the key for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you didn't accept the default arguments in B's save method. Generally when overriding a method you need to ensure you accept all the arguments that could be passed, and make sure you pass them on to the super class method. One way of doing that is with `*args, **kwargs`:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.slug ="%d%s" % (self.pk, slugify(self.title))
    super(B, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: tnx the problem solved but new problem is :Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.  /env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/operations.py in _quote_params_for_last_executed_query, line 125.A.objects.update_or_create(ad_info=info_data, **info_data)  @danielRoseman

Answer (score 1):

After you done the fix by @Daniel Roseman t think you should updated your `validated_data` with new instance of the `A` instance

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    info_data = validated_data.pop('ad_info')
    # Next two rows
    a = A.objects.create(**info_data)
    validated_data.update({'a': a})
    ad = B.objects.update_or_create(**validated_data)
    A.objects.update_or_create(ad_info=adgame, **info_data)
    ad.save()
    return ad
```

Comment: I changed the code as you said .now i get integrity error from database: UNIQUE constraint failed: store_b.slug

Comment: i think slug field that i made is getting dublicated on database

Comment: i did hard refresh and made another request .i get this error again:Error binding parameter 3 - probably unsupported type.  .why i think my structure is wrong? i mean is this a proper way for creating OneToOne relationship in django restframework?

Comment: any idea? i cant handle it my self